# Remove optgroup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove or hide option group of admin user with jquery, help me friends....!

```
<select name="usergroup" id="usergroup">
    <optgroup id="admin" label="Admin List">
         <option value="admin1">Admin 1</option>
         <option value="admin1">Admin 1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup id="users" label="User List">
         <option value="user1">User 1</option>
         <option value="user1">User 1</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**Output is like this :**

```
Admin List
  Admin 1
  Admin 2
User List
  User 1
  User 2
```

**But I want Only :**

```
User List
  User 1
  User 2
```

Comment: where is your remove code. If you want to remove with onload put the code `$( "#admin" ).remove();` onready(); method

Answer (score 3):

You can simple use [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove entirely from the dom or [**.hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) if you want to hide it:

```js
$("#users").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="usergroup" id="usergroup">
  <optgroup id="admin" label="Admin List">
    <option value="admin1">Admin 1</option>
    <option value="admin1">Admin 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup id="users" label="User List">
    <option value="user1">User 1</option>
    <option value="user1">User 1</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Also [**.detact()**](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) will work too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#admin" ).remove();
```

OR

```
$( "#admin" ).hide();
```

JSBIN - http://jsbin.com/wuyuvaseva/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#admin').remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bz694y19/10/)**

You can use `.hide()` also but then need to reset default selected value of select box

```
$(function(){
   $('#admin').hide();
   $('#usergroup option:visible:first').prop('selected',true);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bz694y19/11/)**